Importing .bacpac file with Azure Data Studio on MacBook Pro with M3 chip
I am currently using a MacBook Pro with an M3 chip and I am trying to import a .bacpac file with Azure Data Studio. However, I am encountering an issue due to the requirement of running the following command:
SQL

EXEC sp_configure 'contained', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

Unfortunately, this command is not supported by the Docker image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest that I am using.
I am aware that I could use an emulated image, but I would prefer not to go this route due to concerns about performance.
Does anyone know of any other solutions or workarounds that could help me import the .bacpac file successfully without having to use an emulated image? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I tried running the emulated image but the performance was awful.

Azure SQL Edge on ARM was retired about a year ago. Edge, also, has significantly limited functionality, including lack of support for contained databases (which you want to use here). Use the full x64 Docker Image.

@ThomA so there is no other way then to use the emulated images?

The alternative is buy an x64 device that uses a supported operating system for SQL Server.
